# Monetdb bind function Parameters

Tags: parameters, bind, monetdb

I am trying to understand the MAL statements for joining three tables. I came across the `bind` function in MAL statement. I have a table
named `lineitem` with `l_quantity` in it.  So what does the following statements mean?

1. `( X_94:bat[:oid,:oid], X_95:bat[:oid,:int] ) :=
   sql.bind(X_4, "sys", "lineitem", "l_quantity", 2, 0, 4);`
2. `( X_96:bat[:oid,:oid], X_97:bat[:oid,:int] ) :=
   sql.bind(X_4, "sys", "lineitem", "l_quantity", 2, 1, 4);`

What does the **5th** and **6th** argument mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `src/sql/backends/monet5/sql.mal`:

```
pattern bind(mvc:int, 
             schema:str, 
             table:str, 
             column:str, 
             access:int,
             part_nr:int, 
             nr_parts:int )
   (uid:bat[:oid],uval:bat[:any_1])
address mvc_bind_wrap
comment "Bind the 'schema.table.column' BAT with access kind:
    0 - base table
    1 - inserts
    2 - updates";
```

**Argument 5** is access type. In your example, those instructions are accessing update columns (they only contain updates, not the original data). Later in the plan they will be merged with the corresponding columns of type 0.

**Argument 6** goes together with argument 7. The two instructions you posted 
bind to the first two chunks of 4 (7th argument) of a horizontally partitioned column. Whether and how this partitioning takes pace is controlled dynamically by the `mitosis` [optimizer](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Cookbooks/SQLrecipes/OptimizerPipelines).